# How to set mouse click for listbox that is not currently selected?

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I want to create multiple list boxes that appear only after an item is clicked in the previous list box. So when I select an item in listbox1 it displays the items for listbox2 and when I click on an item in listbox2 it displays all the items for list box three etc.  I am able to click on an item in listbox1 to get it to list listbox2 but after that I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can I set multiple list boxes to display after clicking on an item in the list box previous to it without getting the error?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(1);
        listBox1.Items.Add(2);
        listBox1.Items.Add(3);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string curItem1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (curItem1 == "1")
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(1);

            if(curItem1 == "1")
            {                
                listBox3.Items.Add(1);
            }
            string curItem2 = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            ///This is where I get the error!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the item after you add it:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string curItem1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (curItem1 == "1")
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(1);
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;  //<= This selects the item

            if (curItem1 == "1")
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(1);
            }
            string curItem2 = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            ///This is where I get the error!
        }
    }
```

I would also put some checks in here, eg. the first line could be:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
```

Answer (score -1):

You referenced to **listBox2.SelectedItem** before it was assigned and thats why you received the exception, to resolve the issue simple assign the **SelectedItem** property of listbox2:

```
string curItem1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

if (curItem1 == "1")
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(1);
    listBox2.SelectedItem = 1;
}
```